# how to only define a JSONObject with its keys

Tags: java, json

I want to make a JSON object and define its keys. I will initialize values to it later. Is there any way to do that?
I want something like this when i print the JSONObject before initializing values to it and after defining it:

> education:{ "name":"", "year":, "qualification": }

i.e only keys are there,no values to them exist. how do i define this "education" object. i know its defination can be:

> JSONObject education=new JSONObject();

but where do the keys fit in here?

Comment: No simply you cannot, and prepare your json with empty values instead of no value. Then you can fill it later.

Comment: Did you even try [searching google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=zxAZWr30HYWWjQOMtJrgBg&q=jsonobject&oq=JSONObject&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1472.1472.0.6793.1.1.0.0.0.0.84.84.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.84....0.8UuTUz7k_CY)? I found [this example](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html) fairly quickly. Please review [Ask].

Comment: Do null values solve your problem? `education:{ "name":null, "year":null, "qualification": null }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot have only keys defined. What you are essentially trying to say is I want these fields, but without defining the type of these fields. So even if let's say hypothetically it was allowed, how would you know what to expect as a value for any of the field.

```
education:{ "name":"", "year":, "qualification": }
```

From just this declaration, we cannot figure out is ***name*** again a JSON object? or a String field? same goes with other fields.

So the solution to your query would be, have default values for these fields. Ex. if it's a string have ***""(empty string)***, if it's an object put ***null***.

Then in turn you can modify them as and when you get actual values.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a JSON object and then put each attribute with an empty string.

here is the code:

```
JSONObject education = new JSONObject();
education.put("name",new String());
education.put("year",new String()); 
education.put("qualification",new String());
```